# what is bitnami activemq URL to connect to?

Tags: activemq-classic, bitnami

I have created activeMQ through bitnami google cloud vm, I do not know what URL to use  ,what URL to send messages to?

Answer (score 1):

Bitnami developer here,

You can connect to the ActiveMQ admin panel by browsing to http://YOUR_DOMAIN:8161/. You must use the username and password obtained from the server dashboard. Note that if you want to connect to ActiveMQ from a different machine, you must have ports 61616 and 8161 open for remote access.

You also could use an SSH tunnel like the one below...

```
ssh -i YOUR_KEY_FILE -N -L 8161:127.0.0.1:8161 bitnami@YOUR_DOMAIN
```

...and then browse to http://127.0.0.1:8161/

By default, all ActiveMQ transport connectors are enabled.

If you want to debug errors, you can find the main ActiveMQ log file at `/opt/bitnami/activemq/data/activemq.log`.

I hope it helps.

Comment: i have already connect to the admin page but when i send message to the tcp://ip:61616 port gives me connection time out